# KeyManager in Java Game

Tags: java

I'm creating a game in Java and I'm having an issue with a projectile I'm trying to launch when pressing the space bar. I have an idea on how to do it but I'm having an issue.

```
public class GameState extends State{

private Player player;
private World world;
private Bullet bullet;


public GameState(Game game){
    super(game);
    player = new Player(game, 420, 420);
    world = new World(game, "res/worlds/world1.txt");
    bullet = new Bullet(game, 420, 420, 0, 0);

}



@Override
public void tick() {
    world.tick();
    bullet.tick();
    player.tick();


    while(game.getKeyManager().keyPressed(e)){
    bullet.setX(player.getX());
    bullet.setY(player.getY());
    }
}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {

    final int height = 64, width = 64;


    world.render(g);
    bullet.render(g);
    player.render(g);



    }



}
```

`while(game.getKeyManager().keyPressed(e)){` is giving me an issue with a red line under the e. It can not be resolved to a variable but I honestly have no clue what to do with it. Here is my KeyManager code as well.

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{

private boolean[] keys;
public boolean up, down, left, right, action;


public KeyManager(){
    keys = new boolean[256];

}


public void tick(){

    up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
    down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
    left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
    action = keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE];


}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    System.out.println("Pressed");

}


@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;


}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


}


public boolean[] getKeys() {
    return keys;
}


public void setKeys(boolean[] keys) {
    this.keys = keys;
}

}
```

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong as I'm relatively new. If you happen to have a source for coding projectile launching that is better than my idea PLEASE link it! I need help!

Comment: Did you Google the error to get an idea of what it is and why it might be happening?

Comment: Yes, but I'm having an issue because I feel like I'm launching the projectile the wrong way. I suppose what I need most is a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use key bindings than a key listener.

Here are some key bindings in the context of a snake game like the Atari snake game.  The key method (pun intended) is the setKeyBindings method.  You would add the space bar to these key bindings.

```
package com.ggl.snake.game.view;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import com.ggl.snake.game.controller.ArrowAction;
import com.ggl.snake.game.model.SnakeGameModel;
import com.ggl.snake.game.runnable.GameRunnable;

public class SnakeGameFrame {

    private static final NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    private GameRunnable gameRunnable;

    private GridPanel gridPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    private SnakeGameModel model;

    public SnakeGameFrame(SnakeGameModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    private void createPartControl() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        // frame.setIconImage(getFrameImage());
        frame.setTitle("Retro Snake Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        gridPanel = new GridPanel(model);
        mainPanel.add(gridPanel);

        controlPanel = new ControlPanel(this, model);
        mainPanel.add(controlPanel.getPanel());

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();

        setKeyBindings(gridPanel);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(controlPanel.getStartButton());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        gameRunnable = new GameRunnable(this, model);
        new Thread(gameRunnable).start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings(JPanel gridPanel) {
        InputMap inputMap = gridPanel
                .getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "right arrow");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

        inputMap = gridPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("up arrow",
                new ArrowAction(model, new Point(0, -1)));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("down arrow",
                new ArrowAction(model, new Point(0, 1)));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("left arrow",
                new ArrowAction(model, new Point(-1, 0)));
        gridPanel.getActionMap().put("right arrow",
                new ArrowAction(model, new Point(1, 0)));
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        gameRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void repaintGridPanel() {
        gridPanel.repaint();
    }

    public void setScoreText() {
        controlPanel.setScoreText(NF.format(model.getScore()));
    }

    public void setPauseButton() {
        controlPanel.setPauseButton(model.isGameActive());
    }
}
```